# In React, how can I cause a called component to delete itself from a page when a state changes inside of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

So for example:

```
{!loading ? (data.map((v, i) => {
                   
                    return <Card key={i} title={v.name} image={v.pictures.sizes[4].link}} /> })
```

Now these cards show up as a stack of components on the main paing. In each card, there is a button. when I click that button it changes a state in the Card. How can I get that button to cause the Card I click to leave the main screen immediately without needing to reload everything?

I've tried quite a bit and nothing has worked--> Ive tried passed a parent state function, and dealing with the state inside the child

Comment: Could you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the state out of the Card and into the parent component. Then you can pass in a function as a prop to each Card component which can then be called on the button `onClick` function

```
export const Table = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState<Array<{id:string; name: string; pictures: any;}>>([]); // put your card data in here
  const removeCard = (id: string) => setCards(prev => prev.filter(card => card.id !== id));
  return (
    <>
      {cards.map(card => <Card key={card.id} id={card.id} title={card.name} image={card.pictures.sizes[4].link} remove={removeCard} />)}
    </>
  )
}
```